# Excel copy resulting in image being pasted

Tags: excel, ms-office

I've only just got Excel 2013 (I know I'm late to the party with this one) and I'm loving the new features.  However, I'm finding an issue when copying from Excel and pasting into other programs.

If I attempt to copy cell data from Excel, it's pasting the value as an image and I don't understand why.  So far, I've found this to be in pretty much everything that accepts HTML (e.g. a wysiwyg editor).  What's more weird is that when I paste the copied cell data into Skype, it pastes both the text itself and an image of the text.

This doesn't happen when I paste into another Office program (Word, Outlook etc).  Nor does it happen if I copy text from Word and into any other program.

It doesn't matter if the cell is formatted or not, if it's a brand new document, or if it's from an XLSX, XLS or CSV file.

When I'm copying cell data, I'm highlighting the cells I want and pressing CTRL + C on my keyboard.  Then to paste, I'm using CTRL + V.  I've tried combinations of using the shortcuts and file options to do both the copying and pasting but none have given me the correct results.

At the moment, if I want to copy from Excel, I'm having to paste it into Notepad and then copying it from there.

I didn't have this issue with Excel 2010.  Do you think it could be a setting I need to switch off?  I've had a good Google for this but I only seem to find how to copy as a picture, which is the complete opposite that I want to do!

**EDIT:**
I'm not the only person who is getting this issue - someone else in my office who is using Windows 10 and Excel 2013 is having the exact same problem.  There must be a setting somewhere that we're missing...

Comment: In the other programs, can you do something like Edit --> Paste Special? Or right click "Paste value" type thing?

Comment: I can't see that option in Skype unfortunately and a least with some of the wysiwyg editors I'm testing in, they don't have that option either...

Comment: which other programs does this happen in?

Comment: tbh, it's Skype that's my biggest issue.  I've replicated it into text boxes that allow images to be pasted.  One of them is our work webmail and another is for support ticket websites.

Comment: I've just tried it in Stackoverflow on my existing post above but it doesn't replicate there...

Comment: Okay then it's not an Excel issue.  Excel is functioning properly.

Comment: but if I copy from any other program into Skype and these wysiwyg editors in Chrome, it's working fine, even another Office program.  It only started doing this recently, either when I updated to this version of Office or when I run my Windows 10 update this morning

Comment: Is there a `Paste Special` option when you right click into a Skype textbox?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2702629/paste-special-option-is-missing-or-not-working-in-microsoft-office

Comment: I don't see how this is about programming within the scope defined by SO; it seems more appropriate for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I googled your issue.  It's a Skype *Feature*, not an Excel bug.

> ## Paste Unformatted in Skype:
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

<sub>It's a Skype Feature, not an Excel bug.   ([Source](https://www.skypefeedback.com/forums/299913-generally-available/suggestions/17995402-stop-bringing-in-text-formatting-on-paste))</sub>

Comment: absolute genius!  I can't believe I hadn't already tried this!  It also works in the wysiwyg editors online too :)

Comment: just to note, if I copy the cell data from Excel and then close it, I can paste normally using CTRL + C so there must be something interfering with Excel if that's the case.  However, I'm more than happy with this solution, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  Excel and Skype are both Microsoft products.  Skype is "asking" Excel for the formatting.  When Excel is closed, it's not answering.  I see the there are many people unhappy with the feature, but presumably more people like it, so it will probably stay.